Vue 3 mutation is not reflected on Django backend
In my blog app, I want to like, dislikes and share posts using Vue 3 composition API. I provided Mutation class in schema.py and UpdatePostCounts Vue component. But for some odd reason the mutation is not showing on the Django backend database in Django Admin interface. How can I resolve this? Also how can I embed the likes, dislikes, and shares
as I use SocialMedia.vue buttons?
Schema.py:
import graphene
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from blog import models


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile

class TagType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Tag

class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_posts = graphene.List(PostType)
    author_by_username = graphene.Field(AuthorType, username=graphene.String())
    post_by_slug = graphene.Field(PostType, slug=graphene.String())
    posts_by_author = graphene.List(PostType, username=graphene.String())
    posts_by_tag = graphene.List(PostType, tag=graphene.String())

    def resolve_all_posts(root, info):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .all()
        )

    def resolve_author_by_username(root, info, username):
        return models.Profile.objects.select_related("user").get(
            user__username=username
        )

    def resolve_post_by_slug(root, info, slug):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .get(slug=slug)
        )

    def resolve_posts_by_author(root, info, username):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(author__user__username=username)
        )

    def resolve_posts_by_tag(root, info, tag):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(tags__name__iexact=tag)
        )

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    like_post = graphene.Field(PostType, id=graphene.ID())
    dislike_post = graphene.Field(PostType, id=graphene.ID())
    share_post = graphene.Field(PostType, id=graphene.ID())

    def resolve_like_post(self, info, id):
        post = models.Post.objects.get(pk=id)
        post.likes += 1
        post.save()
        return post

    def resolve_dislike_post(self, info, id):
        post = models.Post.objects.get(pk=id)
        post.dislikes += 1
        post.save()
        return post


    def resolve_share_post(self, info, id):
        post = models.Post.objects.get(pk=id)
        post.shares += 1
        post.save()
        return post

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)

UpdatePostCounts.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="like">Like</button>
    <button @click="dislike">Dislike</button>
    <button @click="share">Share</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useMutation } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';

const postId = ref('');

const { mutate: likePost } = useMutation(gql`
  mutation LikePost($id: ID!) {
    likePost(id: $id) {
      id
      likes
    }
  }
`);

const { mutate: dislikePost } = useMutation(gql`
  mutation DislikePost($id: ID!) {
    dislikePost(id: $id) {
      id
      dislikes
    }
  }
`);

const { mutate: sharePost } = useMutation(gql`
  mutation SharePost($id: ID!) {
    sharePost(id: $id) {
      id
      shares
    }
  }
`);

const postId = postId.value; // Replace with your actual post ID

const like = () => {
  likePost({ id: postId });
};

const dislike = () => {
  dislikePost({ id: postId });
};

const share = () => {
  sharePost({ id: postId });
};
</script>

SocialMediaButtons.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="likePost"><font-awesome-icon icon="thumbs-up" style="color: green; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Like ({{ likes }})</button>
    <button @click="dislikePost"><font-awesome-icon icon="thumbs-down" style="color: red; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Dislike ({{ dislikes }})</button>
    <button @click="sharePost"><font-awesome-icon icon="far fa-share-square" style="color: blue; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Share ({{ shares }})</button>
    <div class="social-media-icons" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 10vh;">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="facebookIcon" class="fa-2x icon-facebook" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="twitterIcon" class="fa-2x icon-twitter" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="linkedinIcon" class="fa-2x icon-linkedin" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { usePostService } from '../services/PostService';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown, faShareSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faFacebookSquare, faTwitterSquare, faLinkedin } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

const facebookIcon = ref(faFacebookSquare);
const twitterIcon = ref(faTwitterSquare);
const linkedinIcon = ref(faLinkedin);

const { updatePostStats } = usePostService();

const props = defineProps(['post']);
const postId = ref(props.post?.id)
const likes = ref(props.post?.likes || 0 );
const dislikes = ref(props.post?.dislikes || 0 );
const shares = ref(props.post?.shares || 0 );

const likePost = async () => {  
  likes.value++;
  await updatePostStats(props.post.id, likes.value, dislikes.value, shares.value); // Pass props.post.id as $postId
};

const dislikePost = async () => {
  dislikes.value++;
  await updatePostStats(props.post.id, likes.value, dislikes.value, shares.value); // Pass props.post.id as $postId
};

const sharePost = async () => {
  shares.value++;
  await updatePostStats(postId.value, likes.value, dislikes.value, shares.value); // Pass props.post.id as $postId
};
</script>

<style>
.social-media-icons {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.social-media-icons a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.icon-linkedin {
  color: #0077b5;
}

.icon-twitter {
  color: #1da1f2;
}

.like {
  background-color: #28a745; /* Green color for Like button */
  color: white;
}

.dislike {
  background-color: #dc3545; /* Red color for Dislike button */
  color: white;
}

.share {
  background-color: #007bff; /* Blue color for Share button */
  color: white;
}

</style>

